# Is the mods tag valid here?

Tags: discussion, tags

I saw that QAvenDreamer added the mods tag to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16124/does-dota-work-in-lan).

My question is why? According to my knowledge the mods tag is unnecessary, because Dota already has its own tag.

Comment: This was a while back, our policy on tags has been ... refined ... since then. I think that question needs a retag.

Comment: @QAdley  "... refined ... " ? That's putting it mildly... :D

Comment: [Relevant meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/lets-talk-about-mods)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No

Just because the answer might involve a mod, the question should not use [mod](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mod) unless it is actually about a mod (which this question is not).

Comment: Question re tagged.

Comment: Well, the question is about DOTA, which *is* a mod...

Comment: @Oak But it has its own tag, so [mod] is redundant.

Comment: You used a big word you must be right

Answer (score 2):

I tagged that question in **February of '11**. That's about a year and a half ago.

Site policy changes, and our tagging policy has been particularly turbulent as of late. It may have been a valid tag at the time, but waiting more than a full year is plenty of time to reflect before revisiting the deccision, so I think that, no, the [mod](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mod) tag is no longer valid on that question.

Comment: I'm quite actively lurking on meta so i saw the "discussion" involving tags ect... So before just re-tagging something which a mod has tagged I first wanted to make sure that I was correct.